# Is there a way to get the environment set in the Jenkinsfile through the jenkins REST API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I set the environment in jenkinsfile like this，when this pipeline has finished，Is there a way to get the environment through the jenkins REST API
for example：

```
environment {
  K8S_NAMESPACE = ""
  ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
  ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = ""
}
```

I've tried using the Environment Injector plugin, but it seems to only support free style projects